# How to covert String to byte for BLE mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic?

Tags: android, string, byte, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing in `Android BLE`.

I try to send string to `BLE device(like TI CC2541)` , and it seems can not send string direct to `BLE device`.
It need to convert the **String to Byte**.

I have search some information , there has someone use `URLEncoder.encode`.
But I am not sure which is the answer what I need.

But how to convert the String to Byte?

The following code is `writeCharacteristic` for `BLE`

```
public void writeString(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BluetoothGattService HelloService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(HELLO_SERVICE_UUID);

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic StringCharacteristic = HelloService.getCharacteristic(UUID_HELLO_CHARACTERISTIC_WRITE_STRING);

        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(StringCharacteristic , true);

            int A = Integer.parseInt(text);

            //How to convert the String to Byte here and set the Byte to setValue ?????

        StringCharacteristic .setValue(A, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(StringCharacteristic );

        Log.d(TAG, "StepCount Characteristic End!");        

    }
```

How to convert the String to Byte?

Comment: Hello Wun, did you find solution for this question? I am currently stuck on this problem while I use WriteCharacteristic.setValue() by passing sting. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following code help me convert the string.

```
private byte[] parseHex(String hexString) {
        hexString = hexString.replaceAll("\\s", "").toUpperCase();
        String filtered = new String();
        for(int i = 0; i != hexString.length(); ++i) {
            if (hexVal(hexString.charAt(i)) != -1)
                filtered += hexString.charAt(i);
        }

        if (filtered.length() % 2 != 0) {
            char last = filtered.charAt(filtered.length() - 1);
            filtered = filtered.substring(0, filtered.length() - 1) + '0' + last;
        }

        return hexStringToByteArray(filtered);
    }

     public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
            int len = s.length();
            byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                     + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
            }
            return data;
        }

    private int hexVal(char ch) {
        return Character.digit(ch, 16);
    }
```

If you want to convert string value. you just need to call like the following:

```
String text;
byte[] value = parseHex(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you get your String:

```
                    byte[] strBytes = text.getBytes();  
byte[] bytes = context.yourmWriteCharacteristic.getValue();
```

Please add a null check too like:

```
 if (bytes == null) {

                        Log.w("Cannot get Values from mWriteCharacteristic.");
                        dismiss();// equivalent action
                    }

 if (bytes.length <= strBytes.length) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                            bytes[i] = strBytes[i];
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < strBytes.length; i++) {
                            bytes[i] = strBytes[i];
                        }
                    }
```

Now, something like:

```
 StepCount_Characteristic.setValue(bytes);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(StepCount_Characteristic);
```

Comment: Excuse me , what is the bytes ??

Comment: Excuse me , Is the `byte[] bytes` use to receive the byte data in `for loop` ? Can I define `byte[] bytes = new byte[50];` ?

Comment: need to ensure that the size isn't less than strBYtes then. Please implement and check if it works, can debug and delve into it then

Comment: can you send/receive the data now?

Comment: Yes , I can. But I use another method

Comment: pls post it here and accept that as your answer, it'l help everybody who's looking for something similar

Comment: Sorry...I forgot to do this. Thanks for you reminder!

Comment: @user2450263 I didn't try for that.